# How to add a class name to a specific elements

Tags: javascript, web-frontend, google-web-designer

> how i can create a `javascript` code to add class name to specific divs only 
>   for Exapmle : i want to add a **class_name** to from div5 to the end of all divs ?

Comment: Please, include your code on the question

Comment: `<div class = "myClass"> Content  </div>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function applyClass(elem_position, tagname, classname)
{
    var div_elems = document.querySelectorAll(tagname);

    for (var i = elem_position-1; i < div_elems.length;i++)
    {
        div_elems[i].className=classname;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Applies class `some_class` to `div` elements starting from position 3

```
applyClass(3,'div','some_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.mystyle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to add the "mystyle" class to the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wanna add mystyle to all divs except the first four

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add a class name from one div to others, I would recommend using JQuery. This can be done like so:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeColor(){
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div").addClass("work");
});
}
</script>
<style>
.work {
  color: red
}
</style>
<div style="width: 100%" class="work"><h1>Hello</h1></div>

<div style="width: 100%" class=""><h1>Hello</h1></div>

<button onclick="changeColor()">Change second color by inserting class!</button>
```

Comment: i wanna add the class work to a num of divs except the first 4divs

Comment: I would recommend giving each div you want to add the class to a class of some sort, then in the jquery, just use $('.classname').addClass();

Comment: unfortunately i wanna make it dynamic so if more divs add to the container >js could handle it directly

Comment: Just put all the divs you want to add the class to in another div. Hardcode the class into the first div. Problem solved!